# Micrsosoft Hyper V with Linux - No network connection

Tags: linux, virtualization, hyper-v

Trying to get Linux installation working on a Microsoft server Hyper V machine.

Install of Hyper V server and client goes fine as does Linux however when booting up the Linux virtual, it's not picking up any network connections?

Tried same installation with Windows 7 which was able to pick up network connections without any problems.

Is there an extra step or configuration required for Linux virtuals that I'm missing?

Many thanks!

Comment: Any details at all on what version of Hyper-V or Linux you're using?

Comment: In what precise way does the Linux machine not "pick up" any network connections?  Does the device exist in the VM?  Is the network driver registering it?  Is the network configuration not setup?

Comment: Looks like Mitt's answer fixed the problem. Thanks to all for help. Unsure what question down votes were for but oh well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need to use the legacy network adapter for linux installs.

Comment: No, not unless you're using a very outdated version of Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Have you installed the Linux Integration Components into the VM yet?

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=11674